# How we can switch from one window to another on same window with same window ID in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried for adding a comment to another question but it shows me an error message for minimum 50 reputations required, so I've updated my code. Now, please help me on below scenario:

I've one dashboard page
In the dashboard, I've grid view which listed users
On click Username, it opens 'new window' on the same page with Username and Password fields
Now I've to entered text in New window
As per my code, it is not working, please help me

Code -

```
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
               "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://web.mauditor.com/Login/SignIn");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("ajay0094");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("12341234");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnsubmit")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'leftpaneldiv\']/ul/li[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement((By.cssSelector(".treeview > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)"))).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("usermgmtframe")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtName")).sendKeys("Joe");  
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/a[4]/img")).click();
    String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Parent Window ID is : "+parent_window);
    java.util.Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    int count = allWindows.size();
    System.out.println("Now Total Windows : "+count);
    for(String child_1:allWindows)
    if(parent_window.equalsIgnoreCase(child_1))
    driver.switchTo().window(child_1);
                System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
                String child1_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
                System.out.println("Child 1 Window ID is : "+child1_window);

                driver.findElement(By.id("modal-close")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("AJAY");

   Output- Parent Window ID is : CDwindow-DD4195D132ED64B192AB85F0846D5699
   Now Total Windows : 1
   mAuditor - Manage Users
   Child 1 Window ID is : CDwindow-DD4195D132ED64B192AB85F0846D5699
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
    no such element: Unable to locate element: 
    {"method":"id","selector":"modal-close"}
    (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
```

Please check.

Comment: provide some code, html.

Comment: @Kovacic Please check I've attached image in above question

Comment: New tab or new window

Comment: @bhupathituraga new window

Comment: U change to new window by using driver.switch_to_window() driver.window_handles(1)

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: @DebanjanB - I've reviewed the code and updated as per my understanding, but in my code new window is opened on the same page with same window ID as mentioned in the code. So now how we can handle this scenario, please check and help me?

Answer (score 0):

for modal-dialog popups u can switch to active element

```html
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("jow");
```

Comment: could you please check above code one more time

Comment: What happened to that code

Comment: For best answer give us URL

Comment: Please check above I've mentioned URL in above script

Comment: @ajaykumar you want to open mutiple windows and sign in each account?

Comment: No, I want to enter username and password for the new window which is opened by clicking assign button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171973/discussion-between-bhupathi-turaga-and-ajay-kumar).

Comment: you can do this one by one or else you can use mulitple windows by switching to windows

Comment: I pinged you on chat window

Comment: If the answer correct please keep tick mark